# Cocos2d: Big background causes memory leak and crash

Tags: ios, memory-management, background, cocos2d-iphone

I am developing a game with a big background, the background is composed by ten images. When
the tower of the game get higher the background scroll down. I am building the background this way:

```
layer.backgroundLayer = [CCLayer node];
layer.backgroundLayer.anchorPoint = ccp(0, 0);
CCSprite *background = nil;
CCTexture2D *mytexture = nil;
NSString *temp = nil;
UIImage *myimage = nil;
for (int i=0; i < 9; i++) {

    temp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"bg_0%d.jpg",10-i];
    if (i == 0) {
        temp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"bg_%d.jpg",10-i];
    }
    myimage = [UIImage imageNamed:temp];
    mytexture = [[CCTexture2D alloc] initWithImage:myimage];

    background = [CCSprite spriteWithTexture:mytexture rect:CGRectMake(0,0,640,2000)];
    background.anchorPoint = ccp(0.0,0.0);
    [background setPosition:CGPointMake(0.0,1000.0 * i-4)];
    [background setScaleX: 0.5];
    [background setScaleY: 0.5];

    //[background setPosition:CGPointMake(0.0,0.0)];

    [layer.backgroundLayer addChild:background];

}
[scene addChild:layer.backgroundLayer z:-1];
```

After scrolling the bg 5 or 6 times the game crashes. Is there a way to optimize the bg.
PS: the size of one piece of bg image is 235 ko.

At creation no memory problem. The use of memory become important when scrolling.

Comment: release myTexture (i think). Are you using ARC ?

Comment: Hi Yves, thanks for the answer, but it doesn't help, the use of memory still high.

Comment: Where are you creating these backgrounds? Is it in the init or onEnter methods? Also, instead of using .jpg try using pvr textures using the Texture Packer tool (http://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker). Using .jpg does not help memory since the images are uncompressed when they are loaded. Using PVRTC4 with a pvr texture for backgrounds is the better option.

Comment: Thanks for the pvr suggestion, I am creating the bg in the method returning the scene.
@Yves: releasing the texture really help :)

Comment: .pvr will only gain on loading speed , not memory. a pixel is a pixel is a pixel. You could do : [CCTexture2D setDefaultAlphaPixelFormat:kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA4444]. That will reduce significantly the memory. Set to 4444 prior to loading, back to 8888 immediately after. If your textures have no transparency, use kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGB565 instead of 4444 (16 bits per pixel, better color rendering).

Comment: pvr with PVRTC4 and 2 formats are compressed formats supported by the graphics hardware. It does make a difference to memory.